# Magento site crashed

Tags: php, magento

I am working on a magento site for a client, just small finishing changes, nothing more.

Work on the code was done, everything was working normally. I just had to change a translation  and I decided to go search in the backend, if Magento had any tools for that (I don't know much about magento yet, Joomla is my speciality).

Well, I think I found something (tab "translation" I think). I clicked "enable" and now the site displays errors.

```
Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: Unable to access Mage_Core_functions.php

Warning: include_once(Mage_Core_functions.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage_Core_functions.php' for inclusion

Warning: include_once() [function.include-once]: Unable to access Varien_Autoload.php

Warning: include_once(Varien_Autoload.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Varien_Autoload.php' for inclusion

Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found
```

All this warnings and errors suddenly appeared in app/Mage.php
and the path these files should be located, doesn't exist (/includes/src).

Nobody touched Mage.php and nobody deleted any files.
The strangest thing is that the site worked, we didn't change any code, only enabled something in the backend. To be honest, I never expected such a crash, the only times that happens is if I mess with the code and in that cases I know exactly how to fix it, but here I'm completely clueless.

I really need help on this one :(

Comment: Ok, I found the problem.

Seems that I did not read carefully what exactly I enabled, I just figured I could always disable it again in the backend (but the back end crashed too so...)

I enabled Magento’s Compilation feature, which is likely to break your page completely.

If anyone else is gonna have that problem at come point, here is the solution:
http://www.magentoweb.com/component/content/article/95-turn-off-magentos-compilation-feature-through-phpmyadmin.html

Comment: basically you just have to open includes/config.php
and put a # before every line. This way the constant won't be defined and the page will work again.

Comment: Please add your solution as an answer and accept it. That's how SO works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is struggling with this problem, here is the solution:

I enabled Magento’s Compilation feature, which is likely to break your page completely. 
You can find the solution here:
http://www.magentoweb.com/component/content/article/95-turn-off-magentos-compilation-feature-through-phpmyadmin.html

basically you just have to open includes/config.php and put a # before every line. This way the constant won't be defined and the page will work again.