# Magento died after compilation: how to disable using compiled files without admin panel access?

Tags: magento, compilation

Tried to compile Magento 1.6 here:

Magento admin panel,  System, Tools, Compilation

It compiled and then I enabled it. After that, site died. Here's the stack (but that's not important)

```
Warning: include_once(Mage_Core_functions.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 36

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Mage_Core_functions.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/mysite/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 36

Warning: include_once(Varien_Autoload.php) [function.include-once]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 37

Warning: include_once() [function.include]: Failed opening 'Varien_Autoload.php' for inclusion (include_path='/home/mysite/public_html/includes/src:.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 37

Fatal error: Class 'Varien_Autoload' not found in /home/mysite/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 53
```

The important thing: how to get it up again? Maybe through editing MySQL tables?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento site crashed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8458136/magento-site-crashed)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

If you've got shell access, running

```
$ php shell/compiler.php disable
```

from the root of your site will disable compilation mode.

If that doesn't work it means someone's diddled with the compiler configuration file in such a way that it won't work with the `compiler.php` script.  If that's the case look in

```
includes/config.php
```

and comment out the two `define` function calls

```
##define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Comment: Thanks! This works. I just reverted that file with SVN, but your comment gives the exact lines to be edited.

Answer (score 11):

comment out the two define function calls in `includes/config.php` path

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```