# Error Processing Request: Mage registry key "_singleton/inchoo_notes/feed_updates" already exists

Tags: magento, admin

I get this error message whenever im trying to login to magento admin after installation of inhcoo featured 2.0 (magento extension) through magento connect:

```
There has been an error processing your request
Mage registry key "_singleton/inchoo_notes/feed_updates" already exists

Trace:

#0 /home/.../public_html/app/Mage.php(222): Mage::throwException('Mage registry k...')
#1 /home/.../public_html/app/Mage.php(476): Mage::register('_singleton/inch...', false)
#2 /home/..../public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20995): Mage::getSingleton('inchoo_notes/fe...')
#3 /home/...../public_html/app/Mage.php(447): Mage_Core_Model_App->dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#4 /home/..../public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13663): Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_acti...', Array)
#5 /home/..../public_html/includes/src/Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action.php(160): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->preDispatch()
#6 /home/..../public_html/includes/src/__default.php(13543): Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action->preDispatch()
#7 /home/..../public_html/includes/src/__default.php(17899): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('login')
#8 /home/..../public_html/includes/src/__default.php(17456): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /home/..../public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20033): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /home/..../public_html/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#11 /home/..../public_html/index.php(89): Mage::run('', 'store')
#12 {main}
```

Error log record number: 214959287644

how can I fix this problem? please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This specific error happens when a singleton (model or helper) is attempted to be invoked but cannot be mapped. Based on the path which I'm seeing in the stack trace, it looks as though you have compilation enabled. You should disable compilation while attempting to install this module, which can be done in the admin GUI at **System > Compilation**.

Comment: This should help to disable compilation mode http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538154/magento-died-after-compilation-how-to-disable-using-compiled-files-without-admi