# Magento Braintree Install Errors

Tags: magento, braintree

Have just installed Braintree extension - keep getting these errors..

> Fatal error: Class 'Braintree_Payments_Helper_Data' not found in
>   /home/my-dir/public_html/app/Mage.php on line 547
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in
>   /home/my-dir/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_functions.php on line
>   244
>
> Fatal error: Class 'Mage' not found in
>   /home/my-dir/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Session.php
>   on line 108

**It happens on the system - Configuration page - SALES - PAYMENT METHODS Tab**

Looks like it cant find files from install - Have Braintree support looking at also but no suggestions as yet..

I think it maybe another extension causing conflict.. I have uninstalled & reinstalled a few times & reset cache.. but still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have enabled compilation and installed the extension.

Go in Admin

`System>Tools>Compilation` , disable it and try.

Comment: Hi, thanks.. it works when compilation is de-active.. but I need compilation to be enabled.. I thought I was supposed to enable compilation after extension is installed..
is there another way I should be doing this?..

Comment: Did you recompile and then enable? Also for more info refer to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8538415

Comment: It was compilation .. i didnt re-compile before enabling.. so Magento couldnt find files it was looking for..