# How can fix the compilation issue in magento

Tags: magento, compilation

I unexpectedly enabled the compilation and worked with code. After noticing thisi disabled it. when compilation is off all functinality is working well. But When I enabled the compilation some of functionality didnt works I can not submit order now. How can I fix this issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Magento died after compilation: how to disable using compiled files without admin panel access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538154/magento-died-after-compilation-how-to-disable-using-compiled-files-without-admi)