# Magento Compilation Turn off

Tags: magento

I tried "Magento admin panel > System > Tools > Compilation" and enable.

The site crashed and getting error message as below;
Fatal error: Call to a member function getCollection() on a non-object in .../includes/src/__default.php on line 20654

Is there a way to disable to Compilation directly from PHPMyAdmin as admin panel also not working now.

Comment: Nevermind, found solution myself. If anybody would need help on it, follow the options mentioned in below URL.

http://support.createhosting.co.nz/knowledgebase.php?action=displayarticle&id=49

Option 2 worked for me.

Comment: Direct duplicate of [Magento died after compilation: how to disable using compiled files without admin panel access?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538154/magento-died-after-compilation-how-to-disable-using-compiled-files-without-admi)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the compiler from ssh also. login to server with ssh and go to magentoroot\shell and use below mentioned commands.

```
php -f compiler.php clear
php -f compiler.php disable
```

You can also run the command from php files if you not have ssh create a php file called cmpdisable.php and write below mentioned code and upload it in magentoroot folder and heat url www.yoursite.com/cmpdisable.php

```
echo exec('./shell/php -f compiler.php clear');
echo exec('./shell/php -f compiler.php disable');
```

Note : this is only work if your server allowed exec php method.

if this will not help then use below mentioned process open file magentoroot/includes/config.php file to disable compilation in Magento, edit includes/config.php and comment this code.

```
#define('COMPILER_INCLUDE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'src');
#define('COMPILER_COLLECT_PATH', dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'stat');
```

Hope this will help you to disable the compilation. Enjoy