# Magento compilation panel cannot be found

Tags: php, magento

I want to acces magento compilation panel but can't find the button under **System / Tools**

[image]

i tried to enable the compiler using this command : **php compiler.php disable** via ssh but the console responds with this: **please run with option compile**.

so i've used **php compiler.php compile** command, and the console responded with this error: [image]

is there any suggestions to get the comilation panel back ?

here's the compiler statut:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like somebody found that compilation was a store breaker in the past and decided to prevent its future use. If the menu does not show an entry for the compiler, the module has probably been shut off manually by changing its `<active>` node to read `false`

```
<active>false</active>
```

In the `app/etc/modules` folder, look in the `Mage_Compiler.xml` file for the following section

```
<Mage_Compiler>
    <active>true</active>
    <codePool>core</codePool>
    <depends>
        <Mage_Core />
    </depends>
</Mage_Compiler>
```

Check to make sure that the `<active>` node contains `true` instead of `false`.

Also, this may have been shut off by creating a Zzz_ prefaced file with reference to the module and the active node set to false.

Be prepared for the possible inevitable that your Magento installation totally falls flat on its face and dies when you activate the compiler.

[How to disable the compiler without Admin access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538154/magento-died-after-compilation-how-to-disable-using-compiled-files-without-admi)