# Default admin tabs are missing in Magento

Tags: magento, menu, admin, show

For some reason suddenly my Menus in admin disappears. Dashboard, System, Reports does not appear in admin. How is it possible? Tried solution [Magento died after compilation: how to disable using compiled files without admin panel access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538154/magento-died-after-compilation-how-to-disable-using-compiled-files-without-admi), but does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Check you are logged in as administrator or not?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is the administrator role and i have access to all menus in admin and it was working well for past month. Suddenly it went down. However, i made DB backup and restored the website. I am curious in what scenario this issue will occur.